# Java - If text file exists, create new file appending "1"

Tags: java, count, append

How can I change my code to look for an existing "Library.txt" file and if one exists, create a new file named "Library1", etc?

I have this code currently:

```
            if(Menu.menuChoice == 7 && Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(Messages.addManualFirst);
                Menu.displayMenu();
            }

            else if(Menu.menuChoice == 7){
                Library.displayManualList();
                boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper® app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                if(saveYesNo){
                    try {
                        File file = new File("Library.txt");
                        file.delete();
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                        for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                            pw.println("\n-------------------- Index Number: " + i + " --------------------");
                            pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                            pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
                        }
                        pw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }
                    else if(saveYesNo){
                        System.out.println("\n");
                }   
                Menu.displayMenu();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `file.delete()`, that will remove the existing one! I think you wanted something like

```
File file = new File("Library.txt");
// file.delete();
// file.createNewFile();
for (int i = 1; file.exists(); i++) {
    file = new File(String.format("Library%d.txt", i));
}
```

which you could read as declare and initialize `i` to `1`, while the `file` exists add one to `i`. Reinitialize `file` (in the while) to a `String` of "Library#.txt" where `#` is replaced by `i`.

You can read about the Formatter syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: This works great however is there a way to append the information to the first library.txt and only create a new text file once the application is closed and launched again?

Comment: Save the `FileWriter` (and/or `PrintWriter`) and don't re-open it until the application is closed and launched again. Also, that's really a different question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how to word my question as I thought appending a "1" would only occur once per launch :( I am new to programming. Could you show me an example of how I can save the FileWriter?

Comment: @James One possible option is to put a method called `File getFilePath()` in `Menu`, return `file` above at the end of that method.  Then your code could just be `File file = menu.getFilePath()`. It's hard to tell without seeing all of your code, and again you should be asking new questions (and trying things). Potentially, your method could be called `getFileWriter()` and return the file writer. Welcome to the world of development.